# How can entropic effects be prevalent at low temperatures?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

I read in a book that at low temperature the hydrophobic effect (for example) is entropic but at high temperatures it is enthalpic. I thought that entropy should decrease at very low temperatures. Hypothetically, can you even have entropic effects at absolute zero?

Comment: It is true that the entropic contribution to hydrophobic behaviour tends to decrease with increasing temperature (cf. [Mata 2005](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0040603104005040)). But in the *extremes* $T\to 0$ $(T\to\infty)$ the free energy is dominated by enthalpy (entropy).

Answer (score 1):

What did your book mean by "low" temperature ? In this case I guess it's room temperature, which is really not close to absolute 0. Anyway, note that what matters is not the absolute entropy but the variations between two states, and even at low temperatures entropy variations can be high between two different spatial configurations.

To answer your question, notice that at absolute 0, TS=0 so that no entropic effect could be seen, in my opinion. The situation would be different at a positive temperature, since even at a very low (but positive) temperature, entropy variations can be important.